# What is this most efficient way to power a high powered 6 V and a low powered 12 V device from a battery?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-operated

I'm looking to power two devices (two amplifiers, an Akai - EIE Pro and a Behringer - MICROAMP HA400) from a battery source (a big 12 or 6 V sealed lead-acid battery). Unfortunately they require different (regulated, but don't know how tight) voltages. One device requires 6 V, 3 A and the other 12 V, 150 mA. Should I use a boost converter to create the 12 V? I'm looking for an efficient solution (at a reasonable cost) and I'm considering using two batteries if it gets too complicated/costly.

Comment: You didn't tell us what battery voltage you have.

Comment: Sorry, corrected now

Comment: What types of devices do you need to power (e.g. motors, analog signal conditioning, and so on)?  How tightly do you need to regulate the voltage on each supply rail?  Can you connect the 6V 3A supply rail directly to the battery and live with the voltage variation as the battery discharges?

Comment: Tried to update the question again. I don't have the battery yet so I can't tell.

Comment: The specification sheets for your two amps should say what the input power tolerances are.

Comment: Yes I've looked for it, but they just say 6 volt DC, 3A and 12 V DC, 150 mA.

Comment: What's a "non acidic lead battery"? Can you point us to a data sheet on such a thing?

Comment: @JoeHass removed that. I got confused of the english term. It's a sealed lead battery

Comment: Lead or lead-acid battery?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have AC adapters for both of these amplifiers why don't you convert the 12V or 6V battery to 220V or whatever voltage AC you use: -

[image]

I can't vouch for this being a good design and [here](http://electronic-dummies.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/inverter-circuits.html) is the site it came from.

It looks like you only need to generate 20 watts so maybe also buying one won't be a big expense. To get this circuit and plenty like it google "20W ac inverter design".

[Here's](http://www.instructables.com/id/Adaptable-24vDC220vAC-Pure-Sinewave-Inverter-1/) another design from instructables

Comment: +1 You can buy those things (12V to 120VAC inverters) here for about $10 on special and $25 or so any day of the week. Problem with trying to replace the adapters directly is that you'd have to also replace the isolation that comes with the adapters, and isolated converters are going to be a major hassle for a small (potential) increase in efficiency.

Comment: @spehro thats a good point about keeping them isolated! I was coming from the angle that the op doesn't know the tolerance on the required voltages nor the ripple levels hence generate AC.

Comment: That seems tremendously more complicated than necessary.  Just run it off 6V and boost to 12V for the low-current needs.

Comment: @ColinDBennett Please feel free to leave an answer of your own. I'm sure you have a good point.